# Azure SDK - NodeJS - Invalid MD5 hashes on re-upload of blob

Tags: node.js, azure, md5, azure-storage

I am writing a script that is using the Azure SDK for NodeJS to download a list of blobs, and re-uploads the blobs to a different storage container.

```
var service = azure.createBlobService();

// download file
service.getBlobToLocalFile(fromContainer, blob, localBlob, function(err, resp){ // resp here contains the MD5 hash

    // re-upload file specifying hash
    service.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(toContainer, blob, localBlob, {contentMD5: resp.contentMD5}, function(error){}); // error here contains MD5 mis-match error
});
```

Some of the blobs - not all - are throwing an error on upload saying the MD5 hash from the blob is incorrect, even though I am passing the MD5 hash from the getBlob operation:

```
Error: The MD5 value specified in the request did not match with the MD5 value calculated by the server.
```

This error only happens on some of the blobs. Other blobs are uploaded successfully, meaning the MD5 hash is correct.

My question is 2 part:

1. How could the MD5 hash be incorrect if I am passing the value received from Azure when the blob is downloaded?
2. How does Azure calculate their MD5 hash? I am unable to re-calculate the hashes, because they are doing some other encryption/operation on the MD5 hash to put it in a different format, and I can't find documentation on how they are encoding the MD5 hash. Here is an example "MD5" hash from Azure that is obviously not in MD5 format:

   8kz7pLKnPFlF5G6gy+0rrg==

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of `Azure-storage-node` module you used in your project, as according the issue on GitHub at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/78, this issue may occur if the sdk version is under 0.6.0, you can check the version of sdk first.

And we can find the [`calculateMD5` function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/common/util/util.js#L356) on GitHub repo. Which shows that it will create the hash object in `md5` leveraging the content of the blob file, and encode in `base64` as return value of `contentMD5`.

So according the method of calculating MD5 keys in Azure blob storage sdk, you may check whether the files on local will be upload to Azure Storage are the same with those download from Storage.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest Azure SDK solved the problem. I didn't think to do that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code with Azure SDK for NodeJS 5.4.1 under windows. It works well. The MD5 issue did not appear. I think it is better to change a new version of NodeJs Server. Here are some links for Node.js Server:

Windows install: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=254279&clcid=0x409

linux install: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=253472&clcid=0x409

mac install: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=253471&clcid=0x409

Comment: Thank you for your help. It did turn out to be an issue with an older version of the Azure SDK.